# Costmap2DROS object is not correctly created

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic, costmap, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have created a node to run navFn using costmap_2d without move_base, as in this link: http://lists.ros.org/lurker/message/20100408.052450.ba663427.en.html (was http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Navigation-planning-without-move-base-td705795.html)

> I wonder where to start to set up a
> simple navigation that runs without
> move_base, in particular a global path
> planner. For a start, a simple A* on a
> static map should suffice. From what
> I've read, costmap_2d and navfn should
> provide the right functionality, but
> do they without a running robot? They
> seem to be tightly coupled with
> move_base and constant sensor updates.
> ...

I created a package: ros_global_planners_experiment

under src:

**ros_global_planners_experiment_node.cpp**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h>
#include <navfn/navfn_ros.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv,"ros_global_planners_experiment_node");
  

  ros::NodeHandle n("~");
  
  tf::TransformListener tf(ros::Duration(10));
  costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS willow_garage_costmap("willowgarage_costmap", tf);
  ROS_INFO("Costmap2d node started ...");

  navfn::NavfnROS navfn;
  navfn.initialize("my_navfn_planner", &willow_garage_costmap);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

under launch: I created two launch files:

**ros_experiment.launch**

```
<launch>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>

    <arg name="map_file" default="$(find rosbot_navigation)/maps/willowgarage-refined.yaml"/>
    <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map base_link 100" />  

   <node pkg="costmap_2d" type="costmap_2d_markers" name="voxel_visualizer">
    <remap from="voxel_grid" to="costmap/voxel_grid"/>
  </node> 

  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" />

  <node pkg="ros_global_planners_experiment" type="ros_global_planners_experiment_node" name="ros_global_planners_experiment_node" >
    <rosparam file="$(find ros_global_planners_experiment)/launch/ros_experiment_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

**ros_experiment_params.yaml**

```
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
publish_frequency: 1.0

static_map: true

map_type: costmap

transform_tolerance: 0.3
obstacle_range: 2.5
max_obstacle_height: 2.0
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[-0.325, -0.325], [-0.325, 0.325], [0.325, 0.325], [0.46, 0.0], [0.325, -0.325]]

footprint_padding: 0.01
inflation_radius: 0.55
cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
lethal_cost_threshold: 100
```

**In terminal:  roslaunch ros_global_planners_experiment ros_experiment.launch**

**In Rviz:**

Map ==> choosing Topic  **/map** ==> display willow garage map
[image: image description]
Map ==> choosing **Topic  /ros_global_planners_experiment_node/willowgarage_costmap/costmap** ==> **empty squqre, I cannot see willow garage costmap with obstacles?**
[image: image description]

**Also,** the ROS_INFO("Costmap2d node started ..."); is not shown !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377450/costmap2dros-object-is-not-correctly-created/) by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2021-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you have failed to set up the cost map. if you change the yaml file as follows, the map should appear.

Point

- Indicate that it is a willowgarage_costmap setting.
- Indicate that you want to use the map topic in plugins and static_layer

ros_experiment_params.yaml

```
willowgarage_costmap:
    global_frame: /map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    update_frequency: 5.0
    publish_frequency: 1.0

    static_map: true

    map_type: costmap

    transform_tolerance: 0.3
    obstacle_range: 2.5
    max_obstacle_height: 2.0
    raytrace_range: 3.0
    footprint: [[-0.325, -0.325], [-0.325, 0.325], [0.325, 0.325], [0.46, 0.0], [0.325, -0.325]]

    footprint_padding: 0.01
    inflation_radius: 0.55
    cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
    lethal_cost_threshold: 100

    plugins:
        - {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}  
    static_layer:
        map_topic: "map"
```

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) on 2021-05-01**:
Many Thanks. It works!

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-05-01**:
Good. Congratulations.